# S Corp Stock basis

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, s-corporation

My wife is self employed as an S Corp. The stock and debt basis forms are asking about stock basis for the year.  If she owned 100% of the S-Corp at the beginning and end of the year and did not borrow anything using her stock as collateral I wouldn't think any of this would apply to her.

Comment: Did she put any money/assets *into* the SCorp?